# Random RepeatCount in AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

How can I set up AutoFixture so that when it generates an iterable, the `RepeatCount` will be different each time? I know I can manually change it each time, but I was wondering if there's some setting that I can change when I initialize the fixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoFixture doesn't have such a feature, but in a pinch, you can do something like this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var rnd = new Random();

var foos = fixture.CreateMany<Foo>(rnd.Next(10));
```

or

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var rnd = new Random();

var foos = fixture.Create<Generator<Foo>>().Take(rnd.Next(10));
```

If, however, you're interested in taking a more principled step in that direction, you should look at [FsCheck](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck) or [Hedgehog](https://github.com/hedgehogqa/fsharp-hedgehog).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a plan to include this in a future release?

Comment: @yinnonsanders For plans, you should consult the [AutoFixture repository](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture).